# JavaScript functions duplicated with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a page with Bootstrap modal windows opening/closing in it. The content of the modals comes from AJAX, as HTML. Let's say I have a button in the modal:

```
<button id="myBtn">
```

and a script in the modal, which also comes from AJAX and binds to the button's click event:

```
<script>
    $("#myBtn").click(function () {
        // do something
    });
</script>
```

If I open and close the modal window multiple times, the function above will bind repeatedly and the `// do something` part will get executed multiple times - which I obviously don't want to happen.

What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: (adding more details as requested)

The data is loaded into the modal, when it's shown:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#myModal').html('Loading...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "ajaxHandler.php",
        data: (myData),
        success: function(data){
            $('#myModal').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle error
            $('#myModal').modal.modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML which will be loaded into the modal, contains the `button` and the `click()` binding.

When the modal is hidden and then shown again, the old content is overwritten over and over.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? It's not obvious, because you haven't explained your goal. Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: I want it to run only once.

Comment: When the Bootstrap modal is opened via AJAX, is the old DOM replaced? Or how are you loading it? That's probably the code we need to see.

Comment: We need the ajax call, what you have in front of us is a single binding, if you are redoing the binding every time the call is made that's the problem, move your binding call outside of the ajax success callback.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, if you want the function to only happen once you should be using [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Comment: According to the OP, the event is being bound more than once, so you will have several `.one` being bound, which means it will still execute multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it's like @4castle says.